# RavenDb Raven.Server.exe service memory leaking

Tags: memory-leaks, ravendb, ram

I've started using ravenDb not too long ago, but I've noticed, that after installation, the ravenDb process is evenly getting higher memory usage (increasing around 0.1MB in a second).
If I leave my computer for a longer period of time - the process builds up with a high usage of memory.

I am not hosting any databases at all (clean reinstall), just using plain ravenDb installation as a windows service.

What could be causing this and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Can you send a memory dump of the process state to the support mailing list?

Comment: question belongs on ravendb user group for community support or ravendb premium support case